# replacing null data with string "null" in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to display table in html page using ng-repeat.
most of the entries in table have null data but i am unable to replace null with either empty space or string null. I tried {{ row || 'null' }} but it didnt help. When it generate table it mess it up completely if rows have large number of nulls.

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="colname in sqldata.collist">{{colname}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in sqldata.tablist">
            <td ng-repeat="row in rows">{{ row || 'null' }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: What you are doing is correct and should work. If it doesn't then something is wrong with the code you are not showing.

Comment: Since there are no borders shown in image...looks like data structure isn't what you think it is

Comment: I fail to see how this could possibly work; you appear to be iterating over `rows` that are varying in length, and expecting that when the `rows` are different lengths, that angular should somehow know which values are "missing";  How is angular supposed to know, if your `rows` don't have an identifying property name?

Comment: honestly, the correct way to do this would be to structure the data as an object, instead of nested arrays that have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 4):

How about the old [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) trick to show something if a value is 'null'.

Replace

```
{{ row || 'null' }}
```

with

```
<div ng-show="row">{{row}}/div>
<div ng-hide="row">null</div>
```

Comment: OP has table cells. Not only original code `{{ row || 'null'}}` is correct but also better for performance. Your solution adds 3 watchers for every "cell". Not good.

Comment: `{{row || 'null'}}` works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mHfRqFQIOARyZSgmmh0) ...problem is elsewhere , probably data isn't as expected

Comment: @charlietfl i tested with JSTL and it actually replaces null with string 'null'

Comment: @Nomad what does JSTL have to do with anything? Inspect your actual data

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use a filter. This means no duplicated DOM elements, a hidden and shown element. It also keeps logic out of your view.

Plus it makes the 'no data' message standard across your application as you can use it in almost all data binding cases.

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="elem in elems">
        {{elem | isempty}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And your JavaScript

```
angular.module('test', []).filter('isempty', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return isEmpty(input) ? 'No Value' : input;
    };

    function isEmpty (i){
        return (i === null || i === undefined);
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hqp5wxc/

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: no need for this when the original code in OP already works. Just adding extra code and overhead for no reason by creating this filter

Comment: And following bad practices of using logic within your view. I agree i didn't answer the OP's question directly and offered what i believe to be a better way to solve the problem. This may be 20 lines of extra code but also make maintenance much easier, what if you want to change the 'no data' message? Find every ng-hide or find every logical Or in your view? This also allows you have to a standard implementation that can be used in many other places. But also thanks for actually saying it rather than just down voting and not giving any reason.

Comment: point is it doesn't fix OP's problem which I firmly believe has nothing to do with the view code at all but with data structure

Comment: And to that point you are correct. I didn't realize it was mostly likely data when i answered the question. Even if i had i would have still written this. Even if it sits at the bottom of the answers it is still a better way to do it and if it helps anyone at all brilliant and it was worth it. I'm sure SO has enough data storage for the few bytes it will take to store this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Another option is ng-if
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="colname in sqldata.collist">{{colname}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in sqldata.tablist">
            <td ng-repeat="row in rows">
              <span ng-if="row" >{{ row }} </span>
              <span ng-if="!row" > null </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Bit of info, ng-if is similar to ng-show/hide. Except it will remove the element from the DOM and re-insert it. ng-show will simply show/hide it.